# Tapestry do not give discriptive errors

Tags: tapestry

I started working with Tapestry and everything else seems to work fine. I run jetty from Eclipse and my development environment in Eclipse on Ubuntu. When i do something wrong it do not give detailed error report as they say in Tapestry tutorial. Do i have to add any parameters when i'm running jetty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is production mode where there is no detailled exception report. The easiest way to override this is adding a system property to your server start script: `-Dtapestry.execution-mode=DevelopmentMode`.

The [configuration section in the docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.productionmode) go into detail where else this parameter can be specified.